# How to write large file with SMBJ from buffered FileInputStream?

Tags: smbj

I have the following code, the file appears on the share and it grows in size, but the code never completes. I.e: `System.out.println("Writing file done.");` never executes.

The `transferTo(...)` is a new method from Java 9+, which pretty much does the standard loop read buffer and write buffer with a buffer size of 8192.

```
try (
        DiskShare share = (DiskShare) session.connectShare(sharee);
        BufferedInputStream bi = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(sourcePath))

) {
    Set<FileAttributes> fileAttributes = new HashSet<>();
    fileAttributes.add(FileAttributes.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL);
    Set<SMB2CreateOptions> createOptions = new HashSet<>();
    createOptions.add(SMB2CreateOptions.FILE_SEQUENTIAL_ONLY);
    String fileName = "test.txt";
    try(
        File f = share.openFile(directory + "\\" + fileName, new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new AccessMask[]{AccessMask.GENERIC_ALL})), fileAttributes, SMB2ShareAccess.ALL, SMB2CreateDisposition.FILE_OPEN_IF, createOptions);
        BufferedOutputStream bo = new BufferedOutputStream(f.getOutputStream())
    ) {
        System.out.println("Writing file to share...");

        bi.transferTo(bo);
        
        System.out.println("Writing file done.");
    }
}
```

Comment: No errors if you `catch`?

Comment: There is a catch and function throws it up... But nothing prints.